# setting up react navigation for WEB failed to compile

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-web

I want to use React Navigation 3.x in combination with react-native-web. 
By going through the "[getting started](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html)"-steps,

simply importing:

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
```

and updating the babel configurations, I end up receiving this error:

> ./node_modules/@react-navigation/native/node_modules/**react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable.js**
>   Module not found: Can't resolve '**react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedEvent**' in 'D:\react_native\App\app\node_modules@react-navigation\native\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler'

In my research I found some topics on github which could have a relation to that error: 
https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/pull/406

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5632

I already used this "fix" (from the github pull above) as a dependecy:

```
"react-native-gesture-handler": "jaulz/react-native-gesture-handler#fix/web-compatibility"
```

but again a similar error:

> ./node_modules/@react-navigation/native/node_modules/**react-native-gesture-handler/DrawerLayout.js**
>   Module not found: Can't resolve
>   '**react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedEvent**' in
>   'D:\react_native\App\app\node_modules@react-navigation\native\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler'

How can I implement a working navigation on the web with react navigation?
maybe using other dependecy versions?
or should I use react router after all?

Answer (score 0):

here are some instruction for setting up 
react-navigation for web apps.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/web-support.html

in short:

`yarn add @react-navigation/core
yarn add @react-navigation/web`

then

`import { createSwitchNavigator } from "@react-navigation/core";
import { createBrowserApp, Link } from "@react-navigation/web";`

finally replace `createAppContainer` wIth `createBrowserApp`